# Find if the passed times are in the range in a php array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$MyArr = array(
 array('1', 'Morning', '09:00:00','10:30:00'),
 array('2', 'Late Morning', '10:31:00','12:00:00'),
 array('3', 'Lunch', '12:01:00','14:00:00'),
 array('4', 'Afternoon', '14:01:00','16:00:00'),
 array('5', 'Evening', '16:01:00','19:00:00'),
);
```

I would like to create a function to check something like this

if **'14:00:00'**, **'16:00:00'** is passed and can be found in that array it should return the first 2 values i.e. **4** and **Afternoon**

**Here's the Test scenario:**

'09:10:00','10:30:00' -> pass **(return '1', 'Morning' )**

'12:00:00','14:30:00' -> Fail

'10:30:00','12:00:00' -> should also pass (yeah, i need to add 1 minute to start time if it doesnt fit) **(return '2', ' Late Morning' )**

'09:00:00','16:00:00' -> Fail

How can i write code for this?

Answer (score 1):

I *Think* this is what you meant. I did a couple of different versions, but you can try them locally and see what they do (or take a look at the [ideone working example](http://www.ideone.com/J6s1M))

```
  <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    $MyArr = array(
      array('1', 'Morning', '09:00:00','10:30:00'),
      array('2', 'Late Morning', '10:31:00','12:00:00'),
      array('3', 'Lunch', '12:01:00','14:00:00'),
      array('4', 'Afternoon', '14:01:00','16:00:00'),
      array('5', 'Evening', '16:01:00','19:00:00'),
    );

    // first one, find array entries that fall between the time specified
    function in_date_range($array, $start = '00:00:00',$end = '23:59:59')
    {
      $start = strtotime(date('Y-m-d '.$start));
      $end = strtotime(date('Y-m-d '.$end));

      $results = Array();
      foreach ($array as $arr)
      {
        // check if $arr times fall within $start/$end
        //if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d '.$arr[2])) >= $start && strtotime(date('Y-m-d '.$arr[3])) <= $end)
        // check if $start/end fall within $arr times
        if ($start >= strtotime(date('Y-m-d '.$arr[2])) && $end <= strtotime(date('Y-m-d '.$arr[3])))
          $results[] = Array($arr[0],$arr[1]);
      }
      return $results;
    }

    // secon one, find array entries that surround the time supplied
    function in_date_range2($array, $time = '12:00:00')
    {
      $time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d '.$time));

      $results = Array();
      foreach ($array as $arr)
      {
        if ($time >= strtotime(date('Y-m-d '.$arr[2])) && $time <= strtotime(date('Y-m-d '.$arr[3])))
          $results[] = Array($arr[0],$arr[1]);
      }
      return $results;
    }

    print_r(in_date_range($MyArr,'14:00:00','16:00:00'));
    print_r(in_date_range($MyArr,'09:00:00','12:00:00'));
    echo "\r\n\r\n";
    print_r(in_date_range2($MyArr,'14:00:00'));
    print_r(in_date_range2($MyArr,'16:00:00'));
  ?>
```

**EDIT**
updated: See the comments in the `in_date_range` function (regarding how it looks at the data).

Comment: Thanks but it fails for print_r(in_date_range($MyArr,'14:00:00','18:00:00')); should not return anything

Comment: @Suman: Your question mentions two times and says `it should return the first 2 values i.e. **4** and **Afternoon**` (which it does). It's just a minor change to the if statement in the function to make it working differently. Can be more clear as to the conditions (more examples maybe?)

Comment: @Brad: Sorry if i wasnt clear. Just updated the post with few test scenarios, thanks again for helping

Comment: @Suman: Please see my updated answer (specifically in the `in_date_range` function).

Comment: Shoudnt we also convert $start and $end values to strtotime?